# Export Doc to PDF Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, abcpdf

So I am using this code, to export a formview to Word.
Its works great..But I want it to export to PDF so that it cannot be edited. Or may be to a word doc so that not body can make changes.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
    "attachment;filename=Report.doc");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    FormView1.DataBind();
    FormView1.RenderControl(hw);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

The problem is, even when I change the content type and header element in the above code, it says that the output pdf has errors.

I really want to either convert the doc to pdf or generate pdf using this code.

Please help.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to create PDFs in ASP.NET is to use a plug in like iTextSharp.  I have used it in the past and it's very simple and free.

http://itextpdf.com/

Comment: Further you can create an HTTP Handler that can stream the PDF to the browser as an attachment that allows the user to view and/or save the PDF. I use this concept all the time in application I work on. Here is a blog entry on how to [generate simple PDF reports using ASP.NET HttpHandler](http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext_reports.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, creating PDF using one of the existing libraries would be more efficient.

But if you're down to use `interop`, you can download s[ave as pdf plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7)  for Microsoft Office.
And then pass "pdf" format to `SaveAs` method

Alternatively, you can apply several properties to your word document:
1. Mark as Final `doc.Final = true;`
2. Restrict editing

For newer version of Word, there's a `Protect` method, that provides a convenient way of restricting editing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178793.aspx