# How to Disable Microsoft Word's file in use box in C# program

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, pdf-conversion

i'm trying to convert a .doc | .docx file into .pdf but the conversion is happening but i get this popup box is there anyway to avoid this

[image]
                                                                                                                                                               here is my code 
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite1\temp\random.docx");
            wordDoc.Protect(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType.wdNoProtection);
            wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite1\temp\random.pdf", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF,false);`

Thanks all

Comment: If I'm correct you only get this dialog if you have opened a file over webdav, is that the case? The code you're showing, does that run in a web application or in a win/wpf/console app?

Comment: @rene it is running in a web service

Comment: You really shouldn't use office interop from a webservice. You will have tons of problems down the line with memory/resource leaks as well as user interaction issues such as what you are currently running into.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export Doc to PDF Asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369539/export-doc-to-pdf-asp-net)

Answer (score 6):

You should forcibly open the word document as read-only...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = wordapp.Documents.Open(@"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite1\temp\random.docx", ReadOnly:true);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.documents.open.aspx for other options that you may find additionally useful (such as not adding file to the recently used list)